# Yocto Multifile compilation

Tags: linux, compilation, cross-compiling, yocto

I have 4 files in different directories.

```
1. /home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/Read/read.c
2. /home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/main/mainfun.c
3. /home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/write/write.c
4. /home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/config/config.c
```

and the `.bb` file is located at

```
"/home/Linux/NXP/yocto/jethro/yocto/source/meta-mylayer/recipes-app/mainfun/mainfun.bb"
```

From `mainfun.c` I am calling different functions, the definitions of which are present inside `write.c`, `config.c`, `read.c`.

I have only come across a single file compilation using yocto so can you please help how do I write the `.bb` file? How can I compile and generate "XYZ_app" executable?

Here I attached my `.bb` file which I have written but it's not working:

```
DESCRIPTION = "multiple file compilation"
PR = "r0"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI += "file://home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/ \
           "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} --static -c  ${WORKDIR}}/home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/read/read.c
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} --static -c  ${WORKDIR}}/home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/write/write.c
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} --static -c  ${WORKDIR}}/home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/conf/conf.c
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} --static -c  ${WORKDIR}}/home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/mainfun/mainfun.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} --static ${WORKDIR} /home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/Read/read.o /home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/write/write.o /home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/conf/conf.o /home/Linux/NXP/XYZ/Embedded/mainfun/mainfun.o -c XYZ_App
}

do_install() {

    install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/XYZ_App ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct compilation of source files in a recipe is a testing/emergency solution at best. Whenever it comes to something even only slightly advanced, the correct way is to use a build system of any kind.

Those directly supported in OpenEmbedded include (amongst others)

- Makefiles
- Autotools
- CMake

Here are examples for a couple of recipes for those systems: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-testing-examples

Properly packing the sources up also gives you a way to easily test the compilation and application without having to invoke the whole bitbake process. All of them have pros and cons, so you might want to dig a deep further. For a start into autotools, this seems to be a good thing:

https://developer.gnome.org/anjuta-build-tutorial/stable/create-autotools.html.en

An alternative is to look at GNU [hello](https://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/hello.html), and also the corresponding recipe.

Comment: Dear LetoThe2nd, Thanks for reply actually i am already went through all docs and also i agree with you that follow standard way is always better. But because of curiosity i am always try to know possible ways. Can you share any example for my question  so it will be more clear for me.

Comment: Actually I'm not willing to work it out completely, as I consider it a waste of time for myself. But some pointers: strip away the lengthy pathes, if you actually want to keep the sources with the recipe then they also should be next to it in the files directory, not some arbitrary path on the machine. And for the linking step, you're giving absolute pathes somewhere on your filesystem, this is about as sure to break as possible.